# Excel pivot table from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: excel, ssms

I need to create an excel pivot table from SQL Server Management Studio but do not have Excel. Can I do this with Google Docs?

Comment: Yes, you can create Pivot tables in Google Sheets.

Comment: Also see this for information on connecting Google Sheets to SQL Server https://www.dataeverywhere.com/use-database-sheets

Comment: Please note that you can create a pivot on sqlserver as well